# spring data,determine whether neo4j has been installed(connectable)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data

I have a spring data (spring boot and spring cloud) project,and add neo4j starter to it,but in different production environments, I am not sure is neo4j installed.

I use `neo4j 3.5`,and add dependence:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`spring boot` is `2.1.8`:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

A repository:

```
public interface UseRepository  extends Neo4jRepository<Use, String> {
}
```

in the `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${activeProfiles:dev}
  data:
    neo4j:
      uri: bolt://localhost:7687
      username: neo4j
      password: neo4j
      open-in-view: false
```

Then in a service,I can use the repository:

```
Iterable<Use> uses = useRepository.findAll();
```

I can launch the project if no neo4j installed,but if I call any method of any other service with a `@Transactional`, it will throw a exception `Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction`,seems the whole project not work.How to make other service class work even neo4j is down?

Comment: first, you have to disable health check for neo4j, that way, you will not get an exception if it's not connected. `management.health.neo4j.enabled`and if it's not connected, you can use any other repository class.

Comment: @muhammedozbilici I set `management.health.neo4j.enabled` to false,I do not get error when launching project,but I still can not use any other repository or any other service with a @Transactional : Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction